# Entity Framework 4.1 Identifying New Entities in the Context

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a base class like below. All my entities inherit from this

```
public abstract Entity
{
  public DataTime CreationDate{get;set;}
  public DataTime ModifiedDate{get;set;}
}
```

I want to set the `CreationDate` when new entity is added to the database.

By overriding `SaveChanges()` method and checking `EntityState` is in `Modified` state I can set the `ModifiedDate`.

The problem is I can not identify whether it is a new entity or not by checking the `EntityState` because new entities and other loaded entities are in `Added` state.

So is there a way to differentiate new entities?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loaded entities are always in `Unchanged` state. Newly added entities in `Added` state, changed entities in `Modified` state and removed entities in `Deleted` state. If you see any other behavior your are doing something wrong or use EF incorrectly. Btw. unless your creation process doesn't take really long time, setting `CreationDate` can be done simply by:

```
public Entity()
{
    CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by going through the items in `ChangeTracker.Entries()` and assigning the current Date/Time to creation dates where the CreationDate-Property is null. Example:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
  DateTime saveTime = DateTime.Now;
  foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries())
  {
    if (entry.Entity is Entity)
    {
      if (entry.Property("CreationDate").CurrentValue == null)
        entry.Property("CreationDate").CurrentValue = saveTime;
      entry.Property("ModifiedDate").CurrentValue = saveTime;

     }
   }
   return base.SaveChanges();
}
```